# Insert line of text in wordpress template, only home page and under the buttons

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to insert a line of text with a link under the page numbering on this page. https://trulyscience.com/

The CSS box is called 'navigation pagination' and I was wondering if it is possible to insert text there via the additional CSS box.

I assumed that something like this would work, but it does not. Also is there a way to only make it appear on the main page?

```
#navigation pagination:before {
  content: "TEXT";
}
```

Comment: You can do it with is_home() condition.

Comment: I don't get to run PHP, I can only add custom CSS.

Comment: Use class `body.home` ... that should be - `body.home navigation.pagination:before{..}`

Comment: Why you need this scenario, I mean you can have wp-admin access just go t home page and add content?

Comment: I need a single line of text to be shown at that location, and if I add content then the whole page changes into just hat senentence. (I want to keep the dynamically created stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
nav.navigation.pagination a:after {
    content: 'TEXT';
    color: red; // change it as per your requirement
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

To show it only on `Homepage` `.home` is a unique class coming only on the homepage. Hence, you can re-write the CSS to:

```
.home nav.navigation.pagination a:after {
        content: 'TEXT';
        color: red; // change it as per your requirement
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }
```

Comment: This didn't quite work, as it blocks clicks. `.home footer#colofon.site-footer a:before {` should work too right?

Comment: Or this I guess. `.home div#content.site_content a:after {`. both don't do anything it seems